# How to get converted values of attribute from Hibernate events

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my application, I'm using `AttributeConverter` to convert data from the format expected by the database into one expected by the application and vice versa.

Everything has been working fine until now when I need to implement a global solution for audit trail. The requirement is that I need to record old values and new values upon INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

Since all of my `@Entity` classes extends a base class `AbstractEntity`, I created a bean to listen to Hibernate SPI events using this class as following.

```
@Component
public class AuditHibernateEventListener {
    public void onInsert(AbstractEntity entity, PostInsertEvent event) {
        Object[] newValues = event.getState();

        // My remaining audit logic
    }
}
```

The solution is partially working. My bean gets called properly when a new record is being inserted into the database. However, the problem is that the values I'm getting out of `event.getState()` contains the data in the format expected by the application.

As a consequence, if I have an enum `Gender` with 2 values `MALE` and `FEMALE` which map to the database values of `1` and `2` respectively. My code incorrectly creates an audit trail record using `MALE` and `FEMALE` as the values.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me how I can get the values Hibernate is actually using for the queries, not the high-level ones in application format.

Comment: You should always be able to create an instance of you `@Converter` and call `convertToDatabaseColumn(Object obj)` on it to transform the values

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: what I get out of `event.getState()` is an array of generic Object. If I do the conversion manually, I'd have to write so many `if obj instanceof SomeEnum`, and then create an instance of matching converter to perform the operation. I'm looking for an easier way out if there is one..